# PayPal dont give ids

Tags: php, paypal

i have following problem.

I integrated Paypal to my website. Now I want to test the PayPal settings. I test it in the sandbox enviroment. So the paying is working very well and after the payment the site redirects to my success.php site.
and there i have a problem.
Normaly it should show something like `mywebsite.de/success.php?tx=83437E384950D&st=Completed&amt=10.00&cc=USD&cm=&item_number=1`

but it only shows

```
mywebsite.de/success.php
```

my code looks like this

```
paypalURL = 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr'; //Test PayPal API URL
$paypalID = 'mywebsite@site.de'; //Business Email
                    <center><form action="<?php echo $paypalURL; ?>" method="post">
    <!-- Identify your business so that you can collect the payments. -->
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="<?php echo $paypalID; ?>">

    <!-- Specify a Buy Now button. -->
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">

    <!-- Specify details about the item that buyers will purchase. -->
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="1 Monat Premium Mitgliedschaft">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="49.99">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR">

      <!-- Specify URLs -->
    <input type='hidden' name='cancel_return' value='http://mywebsite.de/index.php'>
    <input type='hidden' name='return' id='return' value='http://mywebsite.de/success.php/'>

    <!-- Display the payment button. -->
    <input type="image" name="submit" border="0"
    src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/de_DE/DE/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online">
    <img alt="" border="0" width="1" height="1" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" >
                    </form></center>
```

What did I wrong hand how do i get the invformation of paypal for my success page??

Answer (score 0):

Pass the rm variable with value as 2, refer the below:

```
<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2">
```

Once you pass rm=2 then you will see the below variables after the buyer redirect to your website:
http://mywebsite.de/success.php/?amt=10.84&cc=USD&item_name=XXXXX&st=Completed&tx=XXXXXXX

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2">